# Generate pdf file using Laravel as Api and Vue as a Client

Tags: laravel, vue.js, dompdf

I'm using laravel as API and Vue as my client and to generate the pdf: barryvdhhttps://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf package.
I created a page with some statics elements to test it. Here is my code.
Laravel:
[image]
Vue:
[image]

I'm getting the pdf data at the console log, but the downloaded file is coming blank. I searched for other's questions here but no one helped me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you found a solution ? i have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

You can't download files via AJAX request. File download only happens when browser navigates to a location which happens to have `Content-Type` that's downloadable. However, there's a trick you can use. [Check out this gist](https://gist.github.com/javilobo8/097c30a233786be52070986d8cdb1743) by javilobo8, it does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm able to download the file, the problem is: this file comes blank.

Comment: That means that server response is incorrect. Try debugging your server code, check if the authorization works as expected, turn it off for a test

Comment: Ok, but i guess the data comes right. If you can, please take a look at what is returned to vue: https://gist.github.com/andrepaes/2474795e9162240f2c4960c24aac483a

Answer (score -1):

i handled this by generating link with pdf file

Comment: Some code will help to understand your approach. Could you share it?